# How to use child-process-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

```
var promise = require('child-process-promise').spawn;

promise('some_command_producing_output')
    .then(function (result) {
        ...
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        ...
    });
```

What I want is to add some processing after command produced output in stdout. So finally I want to create a function to use like this:

```
RunCommandAndProcess('some_command_producing_output')
    .then(function (result) {
        ...
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        ...
    });
```

The function should use promise from child-process-promise, wait until successful result produced and return promise for processing data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow @ScHoolboy.

I cansuggest you use a basic child-process module from Node.js and promising it yourself in the following way

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const spawnPromise = (cmd, args) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const runCommand = spawn(cmd, args);
      runCommand.stdout.on('data', data => resolve(data.toString()));
      runCommand.on('error', err => {
        throw new Error(err.message);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
};
```

Where:

- cmd - command, for example, "echo"
- args: array of arguments, for example ["Hello world"]

You can call the function as RunCommandAndProcess if you need :)

Example of usage:

```
spawnPromise('ls', ['-la']).then(data => console.log('data: ', data));
```

Or

```
const result = await spawnPromise('ls', ['-la']);
```

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by

```
var spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;
 
var promise = spawn('echo', ['hello']);
 
var childProcess = promise.childProcess;
 
console.log('[spawn] childProcess.pid: ', childProcess.pid);
childProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('[spawn] stdout: ', data.toString());
});
childProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('[spawn] stderr: ', data.toString());
});
 
promise.then(function () {
        console.log('[spawn] done!');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error('[spawn] ERROR: ', err);
    });
```

For the more information please check the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/child-process-promise)